# SQL multiple conditions

Tags: sql

The query below works fine and give result A,B,C

```
SELECT winner
FROM nobel_win
WHERE (SUBJECT='Economics' AND Year=1971 );
```

Further, The query below works fine and give D,E,F

```
SELECT winner
FROM nobel_win
WHERE (SUBJECT='Physics' AND Year=1970 );
```

I would like to make them in one WHERE condition to get results A,B,D,E,F but it fails

```
SELECT winner
FROM nobel_win
WHERE (SUBJECT='Physics' AND Year=1970 )
OR (SUBJECT='Economics' AND Year=1971);
```

In set theory , the union gives you combined results . That is why , I have used OR .

Source

https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-retrieve-from-table.php#SQLEDITOR

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by Fails?

Comment: it returns HTTP 403 for me, which seems to be a problem with the particular site you're using.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query. Get the table structure and the data and create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to test it.

Comment: your answer is 100% correct. no worries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think their online query tool SQLEDITOR contains errors:
 https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-retrieve-from-table.php#SQLEDITOR

When I tried to do an OR query, I got some strange errors: *There was a problem with the request*.
If you run `SELECT * FROM nobel_win` on theirs page, and then copy the whole result (the whole `nobel_win` table) to the other tool like SQLFiddle, then everything works perfecly fine, please see the below demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f33d08/3 

**Just don't use theirs buggy online tool to learn this stuff, use some real database instead.**
Use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or [DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/) if you prefer online tools and you are not willing to install a real database on your computer.

```
SELECT winner
FROM nobel_win
WHERE (SUBJECT='Economics' AND Year=1971 );

|        winner |
|---------------|
| Simon Kuznets |
```

---

```
SELECT winner
FROM nobel_win
WHERE (SUBJECT='Physics' AND Year=1970 );

|        winner |
|---------------|
| Hannes Alfven |
|    Louis Neel |
```

---

```
SELECT winner
FROM nobel_win
WHERE (SUBJECT='Physics' AND Year=1970 )
OR (SUBJECT='Economics' AND Year=1971);

|        winner |
|---------------|
| Hannes Alfven |
|    Louis Neel |
| Simon Kuznets |
```